# org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: JDBC exception executing SQL

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot

I'm breaking my head figuring out what the problem is.
I want to connect MySQL to my spring boot application but this error keeps appearing.
I use A5 to connect to MySQL sever.
also, iI'm very new to coding so if Im not presenting enough information, please tell me.

here are the files of my work

```java
@Controller
public class UserController {
    
    private UserRepository repository;
    
    public UserController (UserRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    @GetMapping("/memberRegistration")
    public String memberRegistration(@ModelAttribute User user, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("userInputs", repository.findAll());

        return "/memberRegistration";
    }

    @PostMapping("/confirmingRegistration")
    public String confirmingRegistration(@Validated @ModelAttribute User user, BindingResult result, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("userInput", repository.findAll());
        
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "memberRegistration";
        }
        repository.save(user);
        return "/profile";
    }
}
```

```java
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "Users")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    
    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 60)
    private String surName;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 60)
    private String firstName;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 60)
    private String surNameKana;
    
    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 60)
    private String firstNameKana;

    @NotBlank
    @Email
    @Size(max = 254)
    private String email;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(min = 6, max= 60)
    private String password;
    
    private String gender;

    private String birthday;

    private String displayName;


}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Confirming Registraion</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/confirmingRegistration.css}">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="registration-header">
        <h3>registration (confirm)</h3>
    </div>

    <div id="registraion-confirm-area">
        <div class="inline">
            <h3>name</h3>
            <div class="first-window">[[${userInput.surName}]]</div>
            <div class="second-window">[[${userInput.firstName}]]</div>
        </div>
        <div class="bar"><br></div>

        <div class="inline">
            <h3>kana</h3>
            <div class="first-window">[[${userInput.surNameKana}]]</div>
            <div class="second-window">[[${userInput.firstNameKana}]]</div>
        </div>
        <div class="bar"><br></div>

        <div class="inline">
            <h3>email</h3>
            <div class="first-window">[[${userInput.email}]]</div>
        </div>
        <div class="bar"><br></div>

        <div class="inline">
            <h3>password</h3>
            <div class="first-window">[[${userInput.password}]]</div>
        </div>
        <div class="bar"><br></div>

        <div class="inline">
            <h3>gender</h3>
            <div class="first-window">[[${userInput.gender}]]</div>
        </div>
        <div class="bar"><br></div>

        <div class="inline">
            <h3>date of birth</h3>
            <div class="first-window">[[${userInput.birthday}]]</div>
        </div>
        <div class="bar"><br></div>

        <div class="inline">
            <h3>display name</h3>
            <div class="first-window">[[${userInput.displayName}]]</div>
        </div>
        <div id="buttons">
            <a id="cancel-button" th:href="@{/memberRegistration}" method="post">back</a>
            <input id="submit-button" th:href="@{/profile}" type="submit" value="confirm">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Ive been googling a few days to solve this problem, but i can't seem to undestand...
maybe I'm missing a few steps?

here is the stacktrace

org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "create table users (id bigint not null auto_increment, birthday varchar(255), display_name varchar(255), email varchar(254), first_name varchar(60), first_name_kana varchar(60), gender varchar(255), password varchar(60), sur_name varchar(60), sur_name_kana varchar(60), primary key (id)) engine=MyISAM" via JDBC Statement
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlString(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:587) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlStrings(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:532) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.createTable(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:307) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.performTablesMigration(GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.java:79) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.performMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:225) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:126) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:284) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.lambda$process$5(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:143) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
at java.base/java.util.HashMap.forEach(HashMap.java:1421) ~[na:na]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:140) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.(SessionFactoryImpl.java:336) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:415) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1423) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:66) ~[spring-orm-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:376) ~[spring-orm-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:352) ~[spring-orm-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1808) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1758) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:599) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1132) ~[spring-context-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:907) ~[spring-context-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:584) ~[spring-context-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732) ~[spring-boot-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:310) ~[spring-boot-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1304) ~[spring-boot-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1293) ~[spring-boot-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
at com.example.demo.MusicrewApplication.main(MusicrewApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'users' already exists
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeInternal(StatementImpl.java:763) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:648) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:94) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
... 41 common frames omitted

Comment: Hi @Karu , can you also attach the complete stacktrace to question description

Comment: Sorry for the late reply
I added the stacktrace!!

Comment: Please add your `application.properties` file also and which version of Mysql are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is buried in the stack trace

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: **Table 'users' already exists** at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32] at

I’m not sure what setting or property your frameworks, which I don’t use, need to be told to create tables only if they don't already exist.

Answer (score -1):

in which Format do you store Birthday in your Database? Is it maybe as Date? If yes, so try in java to use java.util.Date in your java Employee

Comment: Sorry for the late replay.
No, both DB and code are String